# Positive and negative variations of a charge, which is an integral.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f \in L(X, \mathbb X, \mu)$ and consider the charge $v: \mathbb X \to \mathbb R$ given by $v(A) = \int_A f \, d\mu$. Then the positive and negative variations of $v$ are given by $v^+(A) = \int_A f^+ \, d\mu$ and $v^-(A) = \int_A f^-(A) \, d\mu$.

*Proof:* Let $P$, $N$ be the Hahn decomposition for $v$. Then it is $v^+(A) = v(A \cap P)$ and $v^-(A) = -v(A \cap N)$. We have that
\begin{align*}
v^+(A) = v(A \cap P) = \int_{A \cap P} f \, d\mu = \int_A \chi_P f \, d\mu = \int_A \chi_Pf^+ \, d\mu - \int_A \chi_P f^- \, d\mu.
\end{align*}
$P$ is positive if $v(A \cap P) \ge 0$ for all $A \in \mathbb X$. So I know that
\begin{align*}
\int_A \chi_P f^- \, d\mu \le \int_A \chi_Pf^+ \, d\mu.
\end{align*}
But how can I show that $\int_A \chi_P f^- \, d\mu = 0$? If it would be greater than $0$ then $x \in P$ and $f < 0$. So $f^+ = \max\{f, 0\} = 0$. It follows
\begin{align*}
0 = \int_A \chi_Pf^+ \, d\mu \ge \int_A \chi_P f^- \, d\mu > 0,
\end{align*}
a contradiction. Can I do this?

Comment: Hint: examine your definition of $P$.

Comment: I've edited, is it correct now?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding your deduction there (you don't specify). If you could say what definition you're using for $P$, and show how you use it, that will help with the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it would be greater than $0$ then $x \in P$ and $f < 0$. So $f^+ = \max\{f, 0\} = 0$.

It's not entirely clear (to me, at least) what you mean here. From $\int_A \chi_Pf^-\,d\mu > 0$, you can deduce that $f < 0$ on a subset of $A$ with positive $\mu$-measure, and using that, you can reach the desired conclusion.

But let's start from a different point:

Let $G = \{ x : f(x) > 0\}$, $S = \{x : f(x) < 0\}$, and $E = \{x : f(x) = 0\}$. Then we have $f^+ = f\chi_G$ and $f^- = f\chi_S$.

Since $\nu^+(A) \geqslant 0$ for all $A$, we have in particular

$$0 \leqslant \nu^+(S) = \nu(S\cap P) = \int_{S\cap P} f\,d\mu = - \int_{S\cap P}f^-\,d\mu.$$

Since $f^- > 0$ on $S$, that means $\mu(S\cap P) = 0$. Similarly, we obtain $\mu(G\cap N) = 0$.

And thus we have

$$\begin{align}
\nu^+(A) &= \nu(A\cap P)\\
&= \int_{A\cap P} f\,d\mu\\
&= \int_{A\cap P} f^+\,d\mu - \int_{A\cap P} f^-\,d\mu\\
&= \int_{A\cap P} f^+\,d\mu - \int_{A\cap P \cap S} f^-\,d\mu\\
&= \int_{A\cap P} f^+\,d\mu\\
&= \int_A f^+\,d\mu.
\end{align}$$

The penultimate equality follows from $\mu(P\cap S) = 0$, and the last from $\mu(G\cap N) = 0$, which implies that $f^+ = 0$ almost everywhere [$\mu$] on $A\cap N$.

That $\nu^-(A) = \int_A f^-\,d\mu$ can be shown analogously, or by

$$\nu^-(A) = \nu^+(A) - \nu(A) = \int_A f^+ - f\,d\mu = \int_A f^-\,d\mu.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Why is $\int_{A \cap P} f^- d\mu = \int_{A \cap P \cap S} f^- \, d\mu$?

Comment: Because $S$ is the set where $f < 0$, so $f^- = 0$ outside $S$.

Comment: Alright, now I understood everything. Thx again.